# Show 404 error in fuelphp pagination

Tags: fuelphp

I want to use pagination in FuelPHP, I'm using this code:

```php
$config = array(
   'pagination_url' => 'http://localhost/live/public/index.php/admin/accounts/index/',
   'total_items'    => Model_Account::count(),
   'per_page'       => 10,
   'uri_segment'    => 3,
   // or if you prefer pagination by query string
   //'uri_segment'    => 'page',
);

$pagination = Pagination::forge('mypagination', $config);

$data['example_data'] = Model_Account::query()
                           ->rows_offset($pagination->per_page)
                           ->rows_limit($pagination->offset)
                           ->get();

// we pass the object, it will be rendered when echo'd in the view
$data['pagination'] = $pagination;
```

and here's the view:

```php
<?php echo Pagination::instance('mypagination')->previous(); ?>
<?php echo Pagination::instance('mypagination')->render(); ?>
<?php echo Pagination::instance('mypagination')->next(); ?>
<?php echo Pagination::instance('mypagination')->last(); ?>
```

But when I try to click on any pagination in frontend then it sends error: `404 page not found`

Comment: replace your view with <?php echo Pagination::create_links(); ?>

Comment: If I use this then pagination is not shown to me. please help me to resolve problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to have a route set up so fuel knows how to map the URI `admin/accounts/index/:page` to the correct controller.

Something like the below should work in your `routes.php` config file. (Might need tweaking depending on your app)

```
'admin/accounts/index/:page' => 'admin/accounts/index'
```